# How do I set a minimum code coverage threshold for an iOS project?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage, xctest

I'm an iOS developer using Xcode (7.3 and later). I want to be able to set a minimum line/branch coverage percentage for my unit tests, so that the build fails if coverage drops below that.

I've been unable to find information on how to do that in Xcode, but I assume there must be some combination of tools/techniques to get it done. Any ideas?

Comment: I have not heard of such a resource directly in Xcode. But you can use a hosted too like Codecov (https://codecov.io) https://github.com/codecov/example-xcode and setup commit statuses to maintain minimum line/branch coverage.

Comment: Usually code coverage is not a good measure for the usefulness of a test suite. You can have a very high code coverage without testing anything (for example by not adding `XCTAssert(...)` calls to the test.

Answer (score 0):

if you can export a clover test result then https://github.com/exussum12/coverageChecker can be used to set a minimum percentage for a pull request

E.g. 80% of the pull must be covered.

the tool is written in php, but any clover format and diff format should be fine

```
 bin/diffFilter --phpunit diff.txt cover.xml
```

is an example call